# How can I render through similar components on a timer?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a flexible `<Panel />` component, and I want to rotate through 7 panels with different data. Right now I have a method that generates an array of these panels, with the correct formatting and data.

#### What's the most efficient way that I can loop through displaying these on a set interval (say, 10 seconds)? I'd prefer to be able to add an in/out animation, but that's functionality for later.

Please let me know what additional information y'all would need to help. Here's some code snippets:

### Generation of array of `<Panel />`'s

```
    instantiatePanels() {

        var array = [];
        var len = 7; 

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            array.push(
                    <div>
                        <Panel data={this.state.data} currentPanel={i} key={this.state.data.Key} />
                    </div>
            );
        }

        console.log(array);
        return array;
    }
```

### Initialization of App.js

```
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("extranet path .json") //
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(newData => {
                if (newData && newData.length > 0) {
                    console.log("data", newData[0]);
                    this.setState({data:newData[0]});
                } else {
                    console.error('error downloading data, returned: ' + newData);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

### What I do to render a single panel

```
    render() {  
        return (
            <div className="App">
                {this.instantiatePanels()[2]} // for example
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Thank you **so very much** for your help on this. React is new to me so anything you can contribute is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the index in a state, and use `setTimeout` to update that state every 10 seconds.

You only want to call `this.instantiatePanels()` once, so do that before the `render` and save the results, then in the `render` index that saved array using the index from the state.

Also, if the Panel-instantiation is as simple as in your snippet, I would avoid the instantiation entirely, and instead have a render function like:

```
render() {  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Panel data={this.state.data} currentPanel={panelIndexState} key={this.state.data.Key} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And in the component, before the render, define something like:

```
const iteratePanelIndex = () => {
    this.setState((state) => {
        ...state,
        panelIndexState: (state.panelIndexState +1) % 7
    })
    setTimeout(iteratePanelIndex, 10000);
};
```

*(depending on how you're handling state)*

Then call `iteratePanelIndex()` in `componentDidMount` to kick things off

Comment: Where would the useInterval go in that snippet code? In the render/return method or somewhere else

Comment: It would be defined int he component before the render, and would be started by calling it in componentdidmount. I'll just update the answer with another vague snippet for you